# Discogs OAuth with Scribe: Can not connect to remote service

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

I try to conect to discogs via oauth 1.0a. I am using an example from this page:
http://devjay.org/?p=22#comment-979

My DiscoGSApi10a.java looks exact the same. I got a property file and my main class which I reduced in case of searching for the error:

```
    public class Auth2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Properties configProps = new Properties();
        configProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties"));
        String consumer_key = configProps.getProperty("consumer.key");
        String consumer_secret = configProps.getProperty("consumer.secret");
        String user_agent_string = configProps.getProperty("useragent.string");
        // will be empty on the first run, as token is not yet provided
        String config_token = configProps.getProperty("accesstoken.key", "");
        String config_secret = configProps.getProperty("accesstoken.secret", "");


            //this requires user interaction if no access token is found in config.properties
         OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
         .provider(DiscoGSApi10a.class)
         .apiKey(consumer_key)
         .apiSecret(consumer_secret)
         .debug()
         .build();

         Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

         System.out.println("Token RAW: "+ requestToken.getRawResponse());

    }
}
```

The log and error is as follows:

> obtaining request token from
>   https://api.discogs.com/oauth/request_token setting oauth_callback to
>   oob generating signature... using base64 encoder: DatatypeConverter
>   base string is:
>   POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.discogs.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY%26oauth_nonce%3D1825647227%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1420357886%26oauth_version%3D1.0
>   signature is: WbSZr46nikDsZGzo9gSeJcP28Xk= appended additional OAuth
>   parameters: { oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_signature ->
>   WbSZr46nikDsZGzo9gSeJcP28Xk= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce ->
>   1825647227 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key
>   -> IgUpkXTCBbIZNQrlXiYk , oauth_timestamp -> 1420357886 } using Http Header signature sending request... Exception in thread "main"
>   org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem
>   while creating a connection to the remote service.    at
>   org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:70)    at
>   org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:45)
>     at de.ms.discogs.auth.Auth2.main(Auth2.java:43) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:772)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:769)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>     at org.scribe.model.Response.(Response.java:30)   at
>   org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:117)     at
>   org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:66)    ... 4 more

Why cant I even connect to the remote service ?

Regards LStrike

Comment: i would recommend removing keys like your consumerkey from your log!

Comment: (consumer secret key is the critical one, but still i would not share these informations!)

Comment: thanks, didn't thought about it while posting.

Comment: you are connecting OK, but the server closes the connection on you, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824339/java-simple-code-java-net-socketexception-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server