# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException : java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, jersey

I am getting the below error while hitting the rest service from
     jersey client>

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net
>   .SocketException:
>        Unexpected end of file from server
>           at
>       org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:229)
>           at
>       org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
>             at
>               org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
>           at     org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:
>   443)
>           at      org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
>           at   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.jav
>   a:424)
>           at   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:333)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java simple code: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824339/java-simple-code-java-net-socketexception-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server)

Comment: Hello Meiko, I read this post before posting this question. It was not helpful for me. i checked the server log too, Everything is fine there.     Also the same URL is working fine with rest client tools ( Fiddler, Advanced Rest Client, Postman etc).      The problem is coming while using jersey client to send the request. ( Sometimes, result is coming as expected, while some time it gives this exception ).     Also, the URL is having special character in pathParam value,

Comment: hi, i think the marked answer is matching here too... any other information than the error in your question could help.

Comment: Hello Meiko, Sorry for too late to post here.. But, the problem still persists. I am unable to figure out the cause.. Other information is that, I get this exception only for invalid urls, ie I am validating the 404 response as part of my functional testing. Below is the line of code in which request hangs sometimes and gives the EOF exception.                                               
  
Response res = requestbuilder.post( Entity.entity( multipart, multipart.getMediaType() ) );

Answer (score 0):

when using javax.ws.core.Response it needs to call close() after consumption of the response. just double check somewhere there is no leak regarding http connection.

https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/110

http://phillbarber.blogspot.de/2014/02/lessons-learned-from-connection-leak-in.html