# JMeter: java.net.SocketException: "Unexpected end of the file from server"

Tags: sockets, csv, connection, timeout, jmeter

After executing script with 5k inputs from CSV, jmeter logs shows following error:

**java.net.SocketException: "Unexpected end of the file from server"**

Seems like server side has connection timeout set.

What would be the possible solution to get rid of this error?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824339/java-simple-code-java-net-socketexception-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server)...

Comment: I already went through this link, but what surprises me is after increasing heapsize in jmeter.sh, I no longer see "Too many files open" error but can see unexpected end of the file server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you updated your configuration to fix "too many files open" issue, then this means your server is facing Load issues and is overloaded.

There is no easy answer to this, as there is a big number of factor that can explain that among which:

- network contention
- firewall issue
- server overloaded in CPU, disk, memory
- Application not scalable
- configuration issue in hard and/or software
  ....