# SOAP error: java.net.SocketException:Unexpected end of file

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am developing an application which need to call a SOAP service developed using SOAP 1.1.The service which I am calling is accepting the file url(file should be available on internet)and some other information related to file. This service copies the file from location and upload to internal file location. When I am trying to call the service with small files then my application is working fine but when I am trying to upload bigger files then I am getting error as

```
 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: 
 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed 
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:269)
```

Below is piece of code which I am using to call the SOAP service.

```
 URL endpoint =
              new URL(new URL(host), service,
                      new URLStreamHandler() {
                        @Override
     protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url)throws IOException {
    URL target = new URL(url.toString());
    URLConnection connection =  target.openConnection();
    // Connection settings
     connection.setConnectTimeout(60000000*300);                              
     connection.setReadTimeout(60000000*300); 

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
 "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8");

   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.setDoOutput(true);

                          return(connection);
                        }
                      });
    System.out.println("endpoint.."+endpoint.toString());

    String ingestSoapRequest = NPSClientHelper.createIngestRequestString(mimixStr, renditionId, isMac, urlList);

    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ingestSoapRequest.getBytes());
    SOAPMessage request = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(request, endpoint);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    soapResponse.writeTo(out);

    soapConnection.close();

    String ingestResponse = new String(out.toByteArray());
```

Can someone please help me to fix this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this post might be helpful in your situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824339/java-simple-code-java-net-socketexception-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ssanrao . I am checking for the owner of the SOAP service if there is any timeout set from their side. Hope this will help.

Comment: I got confirmation from owner of the service that they dont have any timeout on server level. Now I don't understand what can be the problem here.. :(

Comment: As per the error possible reason for the exception is server is busy / can't handle the load. As you mentioned client is loading file to server checkout are there any limit on file size?

Comment: Nope. There is no limit. Client confirmed that other consumers have uploaded file up to 9 GB.